# Changing uppercase to lowercase in simpleweather.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is very nitpicky of me but I want to change the upper case letters of current weather status to lower case. Mostly Cloudy to mostly cloudy. Also how would I style the text? I've never used html in jquery before.

`html = '<span> It is currently ' + weather.currently + ' and </span>';`

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eNwzJp

http://simpleweatherjs.com/

Comment: you don't need jquery for this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yNdJOL

Answer (score 1):

Just use

> weather.currently.toLowerCase()

For style you can add the class to your span tag

```
<span class="sample">
```

and provide style details in css -

```
.sample {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a javascript method toLowerCase() and toUpperCase() to solve your problem. Reference is [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tolowercase.asp).

So do:

```
weather.currently.toLowerCase()
```

For the styling you can check this [site](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_text.asp)